# Callback button in Android not working

Tags: android, button, callback

I'm pretty new to Android and I'm trying to program some very easy application with a button and a callback to a new Intent (a new window basically).

This is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Onclick "Start Game" button
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startGame);
    tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Level1Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
[...]
```

As you can see I have a button (startGame) and a textView (textView1). My problem is simply that when I click on the startGame button, nothing happens (neither the TextView changes to "clicked" nor the screen changes). The button as well as the TextView are set up correctly since Eclipse doesn't complain, but still the thing doesn't work.

Here is the XML snippet of the view:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/startGame" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Start Game"></Button>
<TextView android:text="change" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

I believe my problem is really stupid and I just can't see it.

Thanks

EDIT:

I discovered that the problem was related to the fact that I have more than one button in the view, thus more than one callback (on different buttons of course). As soon as I commented the other callbacks, the `startGame` button started working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add in your manifest file one tag then it will work fine. And the tag is ->

1. activity android:name="Level1Activity"

remember add this tag within application tag of your manifest file,rest your code is fine. Try it definitely going to work.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why but this solved it! I thought it was not related to the activity launching but to the fact that the input was not taken (the TextView was not changing). Still, Android black magic. Thanks!

Comment: Ya try it man it will surely going to work. And if my answer worked then upvote it.

Comment: Actually there is a concept of activity stack in android. Whenever you fire an intent to reach from one activity to another it is added to activity stack and if your application not containing that activity which you want to go then how do intent going to fire so that is why we have to add activity name under application tag of manifest file of application.

Comment: Yep indeed. The thing is that if that was the actual problem I would have received from Android some kind of error as I pressed the button: this was not the case. Very strange :).

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell what will be happened.

```
   start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Level1Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Eclipse complains on `.setOnClickListener` and `OnClickListener()`. As suggestions it says to create an OnClickListener class.

Comment: instead of creating select  'Import OnClickListener()' in that options.

Comment: click cursor on onClickListener() and pres F2 then you can see a dialog with 'OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type', from that select Import 'OnClickListener()'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Manifest is correct?
Else this is gonna work for sure...

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Level1Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });
```